Не работает Debug mode для Rider
Запуская конфигурацию приложения для отладки docker контейнеров (приложение ASP.NET). Не заходит в debug mode, не подключается к контейнеру.
Попробовав подключиться к контейнеру через Attach To Process, выводит предупреждение об "Unable to prepare debugger sidecar".

Аккумуляция знаний на SO самоответами

Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос — оставьте только вопрос, текст ответа уберите. Ответьте на свой вопрос с помощью добавления ответа. Задавать вопрос с текстом ответа не стоит

Решение: Проверьте, чтобы в папке по пути ~/.local/share/JetBrains/RiderRemoteDebugger/<Версия Rider> лежала папка Linux64, которая должна быть непустой. Если папка пустая, то необходимо скачать RemoteDebbugger по ссылке.
P.S. По моему предполежению, это связано с тем, что JetBrains ограничили скачивание своих продуктов для пользователей из России. И явного вывода 451 Http статус кода в Rider нет, как это сделано на сайте JetBrains.
Аткуально на 03.10.2024.
